# Does the damage bonus from Disruption affect itself?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

My Disruption rune says "Targets hit by Arcane Torrent become Disrupted for 6 seconds, causing them to take 15% additional damage from any attacks that deal Arcane damage."

Does this bonus include subsequent hits of Arcane Torrent?  I find this skill very impractical to use unless I'm in a spot where I can sit down and hold the button down (it takes too long for the first projectile to hit) so this greatly interests me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Arcane Torrent does arcane damage, so the 2nd missile and every one thereafter will benefit from the damage bonus.

Comment: I assume the rune bonus doesn't stack?

Comment: No. As mentioned elsewhere on this site, buffs and debuffs never stack with themselves unless explicitly mentioned.